# Let S ⊂ R be a nonempty bounded set. Then there exist monotone sequences ${x_n}$ and ${y_n}$ such that $x_n$, $y_n$ ∈ $S$

Tags: real-analysis

Let S ⊂ R be a nonempty bounded set. Then there exist monotone sequences ${x_n}$ and ${y_n}$ such that $x_n$, $y_n$ ∈ $S$ and $\sup S = \lim_{n→∞} x_n$ and $\inf S = \lim_{n→∞} y_n$

How can I prove this ..?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x:=\sup S\in \mathbb R$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there is an $x_n\in S$ such that $x_n+1/n\geq x$ (otherwise $x$ could not be the supremum). We also know that $x_n\leq x$ by definition of supremum. Therefore $|x_n-x|\leq 1/n$. Can you finish it off from here?

Comment: This shows the limit characterization of supreuma but it doesn't guarantee that the sequence is montone.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \sup S$.  We're going to have two cases.  If $x$ is the maximum then let $a_n = x$ and we have a monotone sequence that converges to $x$.  Otherwise consider the following:

Then by the epsilon characterization of supremum given an $n$ we know $\exists a_n$ such that $a_n \in (x - 1/n, x)$.  Then let $a_{n+1} \in (\max(a_n, x - 1/n), x)$.  This must converge to $x$ because $x-1/n$ converges to $x$.  We also know that $A$ is a monotone sequence because given $a_n$ we know $a_{n+1} > a_n$ because it is in the interval $(\max(a_n, x - 1/n), x)$.

To construct this sequence for the infimum you just need to use the minimum and use the epsilon characterization of infimum instead.  It's basically the same proof.

Comment: so second case $a_{n}$ is maximum not supremum ?

Comment: I don't understand $a_{n+1}∈(max(a_{n},x−1/n),x)$

Comment: how did you get that part.. ? I understand $a_{n}∈(x−1/n,x)$.

Comment: $a_{n}∈(x−1/n,x)$ means $x-1/n < a_n < x$. $x-1/n < a_n < a_{n+1} < x $ 
This is what I thought. but this doesn't seem like $a_{n+1}∈(max(a_{n},x−1/n),x)$

Comment: The idea of $(\max(a_n, x - 1/n), x)$ is for every $a_{n+1}$ we want an interval greater than $a_n$ and less than the supremum.  If we did just $(x - 1/n, x)$ then we couldn't guarantee that $A$ was monotone and if we did just $(a_n, x)$ we couldn't guarantee convergence to the supremum.

Comment: To me, $(max(a_{n},x−1/n),x)$ should be $(max(x-1/n,a_{n}),x)$ because from $a_{n}$'s intervals,  $a_{n}$ should be greater than $x-1/n$. can you explain about this..?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Those two things are the same.  The order in which things are in a max statement doesn't matter.  Let me write it a different way.  Let $b_{n+1} = \max(a_n, x-1/n)$.  Then we want to pick an $a_n \in (b_{n+1}, x)$.  We calculate the max bit before finding the actual interval.

Comment: I understand ! Thank you so much